# Best way to handle splitting a Windows or Linux path

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I have two Strings:

```
C:\Users\Bob\My Documents
/Users/Bob/Documents
```

I have managed to conjure this regex:

```
preg_split('/(?<=[\/\\\])(?![\/\\\])/', $string)
```

that will return

```
Array
(
    [0] => C:\
    [1] => Users\
    [2] => Bob\
    [3] => My Documents
)

Array
(
    [0] => /
    [1] => Users/
    [2] => Bob/
    [3] => Documents
)
```

However, I am looking for

```
Array
(
    [0] => C:\
    [1] => Users
    [2] => Bob
    [3] => My Documents
)

Array
(
    [0] => /
    [1] => Users
    [2] => Bob
    [3] => Documents
)
```

ie Trailing slashes not present in corrected arrays

Comment: Any reason why you can't just split it by `/` or `\` and add `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` to the first index?

Comment: You either can split with the delimiter or without, but not with on the first part, and w/o on the other parts. Please read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Comment: @Lekensteyn I assume you mean the PHP Predefined constant? Whilst a good approach the paths are not relevant to the hosted environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just check for "/" or "\" and then use [`explode`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) with the appropriate delimiter?

```
<?php
$s1 = 'C:\\Users\\Bob\\My Documents';
$s2 = '/Users/Bob/Documents';

function mySplit($s) {
    if(strpos($s, '/') !== false) {
        $d = '/';
    }elseif(strpos($s,'\\') !== false) {
        $d = '\\';
    }else {
        throw new Exception('Valid delimiter not found.');
    }

    $ret = explode($d, $s);
    $ret[0] .= $d;

    return $ret;
}

echo '<pre>' . print_r(mySplit($s1),true) . '</pre>';
echo '<pre>' . print_r(mySplit($s2),true) . '</pre>';
?>
```

(Updated with a slightly tidier version)

Comment: I used `strpos()` instead of `strstr()`. As per the PHP manual: **Note:

If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function strpos() instead.**

Answer (score 2):

```
$dirs = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $string);
$dirs[0] .= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

Comment: I like how short this is.  Unfortunately, it doesn't properly parse a Windows-style path when it runs on a Linux machine (and vice-versa).

Comment: @MarkBiek Yeah, but it's a very rare need to parse non-host machine's path. At least in my experience :)

Comment: It sounds like, in Vanthel's case, he has to parse paths not related to the host environment.

Comment: @MarkBiek Perhaps. He has chosen the answer which fits his needs the best.

Comment: In that regard a neat answer defining the separator using `$delim = (strpos($string, '/') ? '/' : '\\')` or similiar function could work?

Comment: Although now that I think about it this is almost identical to Mark's Answer!

Comment: @Vanthel, you could certainly do that as long as you're confident in your inputs.

Comment: @Vanthel Yes this will work except you should test it like this: `$delim = ((strpos($string, '/') !== false) ? '/' : '\\')` because zero evaluates to false too.

Answer (score 1):

With the following code you get what you want, but the first key will also be without the slash:

```php
preg_split('#(?<=)[/\\\]#', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you have already accepted an answer but there is a very simple, one line solution to this problem that I use regularly, and I feel it needs to be posted here:

```
$pathParts = explode('/', rtrim(str_replace('\\', '/', $path)));
```

This replaces backslashes with forward slashes, trims any trailing slashes, and explodes. This can be done safely, since windows paths cannot contain forward slashes, and linux paths cannot contain backslashes.

The resulting array does not look *exactly* like the one you have described above - the root part of the path will not contain a slash - but it is actually better represented this way anyway. This is because the root of the path (i.e. the `C:\` or '/') is not actually that useful when stored with the slashes. With the result of this, you can call `implode('/', $pathParts);` and get a valid path back, whereas with you array you would end up with an extra slash at the root. Also, `\Users\User\My Documents` (without the drive letter) is still a valid path on Windows, it just implies the current working volume.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. And great explanation. I agree in most cases this answer is more than appropriate and I have no doubt I will make use of this sometime. But in my case the original answer is still closest to what I require (where the root is useful, hence my efforts to preserve it).